# Java clock independent to all other operations

Tags: java, clock

I am trying to simulate a live data stream, to test a program that is constantly filtering and computing data points. Mainly I need to make sure that it will meet timing.

Every 50 milliseconds there will be a new data point that will need to be computed on.

So I would like to create a java clock that is independent of what is currently running in the jvm or anything like that happening on the system.

So my question is two fold:

first of all, System.currentTimeMillis() will not be what I want here because it is based on when the jvm was opened, and it would happen when ever the system call gets executed.

second, how do i make a thread that will be constantly running and always trigger exactly on the 50ms mark?

Comment: `new Thread(new Runnable() { public void run() { while(true) { //some logic... } } }).start()`

Comment: What do you mean by "and it would happen when ever the system call gets executed"?

Comment: What do you mean by *"System.currentTimeMillis() ... is based on when the jvm was opened"*?

Comment: And by *"System.currentTimeMillis() ... would happen when ever the system call gets executed"*?

Comment: In order for you to get an update on the time you have to actually execute the line System.currentTimeMillis(). where i wanted it to simulate an interrupt at a fixed time interval so independent of when my program would get around to executing this line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's pretty good, pre-defined mechanism (comparing to pure threading) of Timers and TimerTask:

```
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class Reminder {
    Timer timer;

    public Reminder(int seconds) {
        timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new RemindTask(), seconds*1000);
    }

    class RemindTask extends TimerTask {
        public void run() {
            System.out.format("Time's up!%n");
            timer.cancel(); //Terminate the timer thread
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new Reminder(5);
        System.out.format("Task scheduled.%n");
    }
}
```

(took from: http://enos.itcollege.ee/~jpoial/docs/tutorial/essential/threads/timer.html)

This mechanism allows you to execute your code in RemindTask's run() method every 5 seconds (that value was specified in code)

Comment: @AlexRellim. If it works for you you should make the hollow check mark turn green

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [`ScheduledExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html), more specifically the [`scheduleAtFixedRate()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#scheduleAtFixedRate%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29) method.

It allows you to perform an operation at regular intervals.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [ScheduledExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html).
Here is an example:

```
ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
public void run() { 
    //New data point
}
}, 0, 50,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS );
```